# How to set up a mirrored queue that will work when the master node goes down?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a cluster of two rabbitmq servers in my dev environment and I want to make it so that the queue and all of the messages will be available when the original master goes down.

I made a durable queue on a durable exchange with the following attributes:

ha-mode : all

ha-sync-mode : automatic

x-queue-master-locator : min-masters

I also published a persistant message to the queue.
When I bring down the host that is the master for the queue the state changes to down. I expected that ha-mode all would copy the queue and its messages to all nodes, that ha-sync-mode would keep the nodes synced, and that x-queue-master-locator would move the queue to the other node or in production to the node with the least queues. How do I set up a queue so that I can achieve this?

Edit(More info):

Server info:

rmq: 3.7.17

Erlang: 22.0.7

My config for both nodes:

```
vm_memory_high_watermark.relative = 0.65

vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio = 0.8

disk_free_limit.relative = 2.0

channel_max = 32

num_acceptors.tcp = 20

num_acceptors.ssl = 0

handshake_timeout = 10000

frame_max = 160000

mirroring_sync_batch_size = 1024

background_gc_enabled = true

background_gc_target_interval = 300000
```

Comment: It takes time for the queue master to change nodes. How long did you wait?

Comment: @LukeBakken Just a few mins, how long should I expect it to take?

Comment: @LukeBakken Definitely not a issue with my patience. Its not going to change nodes.

Comment: At this point I would enable debug logging, re-run your test, and check the log files. stackoverflow is not a good forum for continued diagnosis so I suggest posting this to the [`rabbitmq-users`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) mailing list. Please be sure to provide the exact steps you're using to perform this test. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These attributes mean nothing when you create a queue with them. You need to create a Policy that adds these attributes to the queue.